# Finding p and q in RSA encryption algorithm

Tags: cryptography, rsa, number-theory

How to find the factors of `p` and `q` when `e`, `d` and `n` are known in RSA encryption algorithm. I tried to search but could not find any source. Any hint, reference or solution would suffice.

(`e,n)` and `(d,n)` are public and private keys respectively and `n = pq`.

Comment: The only way to find `p` and `q` is to factor `n`, which is hard.

Comment: @user448810 Are you sure it still holds when decryption key, `d` is also known? Is it still computationally not feasible?

Comment: You can try [this algorithm](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_factorize_n.html), but it doesn't always work.

Comment: The algorithm user448810 points to is probabilistic. Each attempt has a chance of succeeding with probability at least 1/2. Hence the expected number of tries until success is just 2. Hence it is a very efficient algorithm to use.

Comment: @user448810 If you know `e`, `d` and `n` factoring is easy. It's only hard if you don't know `d`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography in general, without specific coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [source written in german (page 12+13)](http://www.sec.in.tum.de/assets/lehre/ss09/kryptographie/Kapitel.7.pdf), that describes a randomized algorithm to compute `p` and `q`.

Algorithm:

1. Compute `s = max { t : 2t | (ed-1) }` and `k = (ed-1) / (2s)`
2. Choose a random number `a` in `[2,n-1]`
3. compute `g = gcd(a,n)`
4. if `g > 1  ⇒  g = p` and `q = n/g`.
   else  do for `t = s-1, ... ,0`:

   1. `g = gcd( ak ⋅ 2t, n )`
   2. if `g < n  ⇒  g = p` and `q = n/g`.
      else choose a new random number `a` in `[2,n-1]` and go to 3.

If you choose `a` as a random number (uniformly distributed), the probability to find `p` and `q` is `1/2`, so it's expected to get the solution after 2 tries.

The proof that this works has something to do with [chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Remark: If you have already the private key, there is most likely no reason to compute the factors of `n`, because there should never be more than one pair of keys `(e,d)` to the same `n`. But you can use this algorithm to proof that breaking RSA is as hard as factoring `n`. (RSA is not harder than factoring, since you can simply compute the private key `d` if you have `p` and `q`).